# Selenoid[/usr/bin/selenoid: browsers config: read error: open /etc/selenoid/browsers.json: no such file or directory]

Tags: selenoid

While working in Selenoid with Docker, in docker logs I can see the error as " [/usr/bin/selenoid: browsers config: read error: open /etc/selenoid/browsers.json: no such file or directory]" . My volume mapping is "-v $PWD/config/:/etc/selenoid/:ro" . if I do "cat $PWD/config/browsers.json" , my browsers.json content is opened and same I can validate manually as well that file is present .

Below commands I am using . These commands I am executing directly through Jenkins . In My local same exact command is working fine , but in jenkins its giving error .

```
mkdir -p config

cat <$PWD/config/browsers.json
{
"firefox": {
"default": "57.0",
"versions": {
"57.0": {
"image": "selenoid/firefox:90.0",
"port": "4444",
"path": "/wd/hub"
},
"58.0": {
"image": "selenoid/firefox:90.0",
"port": "4444",
"path": "/wd/hub"
},
"59.0": {
"image": "selenoid/firefox:90.0",
"port": "4444",
"path": "/wd/hub"
}
}

}
}
EOF

    chmod +rwx $PWD/config/browsers.json
    cat $PWD/config/browsers.json
    docker pull aerokube/selenoid:latest
    docker pull aerokube/cm:latest
    docker pull aerokube/selenoid-ui:latest
    docker pull selenoid/video-recorder:latest-release
    docker pull selenoid/vnc_chrome:92.0
    docker pull selenoid/vnc_firefox:90.0
    
    docker stop selenoid ||true
    docker rm selenoid ||true

    docker run -d --name selenoid -p 4444:4444 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    -v $PWD/config/:/etc/selenoid/:ro aerokube/selenoid
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explaining: you don't have browsers.json in directory you are mounting to `/etc/selenoid` inside container. I would recommend using absolute paths instead of $PWD variable.

Comment: Hi @vania-pooh,browser.json is already present there in my directory .Even I am able to see it and same is opening using cat command as well with the same path.Please note that I am running this from jenkins job.           
+ chmod +rwx /var/jenkins_home/workspace/selenoid/config/browsers.json
+ cat /var/jenkins_home/workspace/selenoid/config/browsers.json
+ docker run -d --name selenoid -p 4444:4444 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/selenoid/config/:/etc/selenoid/:ro aerokube/selenoid -conf /var/jenkins_home/workspace/selenoid/config/browsers.json

Comment: Anyway this is not related to Selenoid. Probably you have an issue with Docker then.